# Sencha Touch - Why isn't this List Showing up?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this List won't show up in the Navigation View I've created in Sencha Touch.  Only the title bar shows up, with a blank screen below it.

```
var topView = Ext.define("Parks.view.Main", {
    extend: "Ext.navigation.View",
    fullscreen: true,
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                title: "Parks & Rec",
                padding: 10,
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: "list", 
                    fullscreen: true, 
                    itemTpl: "{name}",
                    data: [{name: "Local Parks"}, {name: "Local Monuments"}],
                    listeners: {
                        select: function(view, record){

                        }
                    }
                }
                ]

            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fullscreen` config only on your `Parks.view.Main`. To fit your `list` component inside parent container you can use `fit` layout:

```
Ext.define("Parks.view.Main", {
    extend: "Ext.navigation.View",
    fullscreen: true,
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                title: "Parks & Rec",
                padding: 10,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: "list", 
                    itemTpl: "{name}",
                    data: [{name: "Local Parks"}, {name: "Local Monuments"}],
                    listeners: {
                        select: function(view, record){

                        }
                    }
                }
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Parks.view.Main'));
```